# Run rails code after an update to the database has commited, without after_commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, resque

I'm trying to battle some race cases with my background task manager. Essentially, I have a `Thing` object (already exists) and assign it some properties, and then save it. After it is saved with the new properties, I queue it in Resque, passing in the ID.

```
thing = Thing.find(1)
puts thing.foo # outputs "old value"
thing.foo = "new value"
thing.save
ThingProcessor.queue_job(thing.id)
```

The background job will load the object from the database using `Thing.find(thing_id)`.

The problem is that we've found Resque is so fast at picking up the job and loading the `Thing` object from the ID, that it loads a stale object. So within the job, calling `thing.foo` will still return "old value" like 1/100 times (not real data, but it does not happen often).

We know this is a race case, because rails will return from `thing.save` *before the data has actually been commit to the database* (postgresql in this case).

Is there a way in Rails to only execute code AFTER a database action has commit? Essentially I want to make sure that by the time Resque loads the object, it is getting the freshest object. I know this can be achieved using an `after_commit` hook on the `Thing` model, but I don't want it there. I only need this to happen in this one specific context, not every time the model has commit changed to the DB.

Answer (score 4):

You can put in a transaction as well. Just like the example below:

```
transaction do
  thing = Thing.find(1)
  puts thing.foo # outputs "old value"
  thing.foo = "new value"
  thing.save
end
ThingProcessor.queue_job(thing.id)
```

---

Update: there is a gem which calls After Transaction, with this you may solve your problem. Here is the link:
http://xtargets.com/2012/03/08/understanding-and-solving-race-conditions-with-ruby-rails-and-background-workers/

Comment: So running a transaction will block execution of `ThingProcessor.queue_job(thing.id)` until all queries in the transaction block have commit? I thought transaction blocks just ensured that if there was a failure in any database actions within the block, everything is backed out. A database feature. Not a ruby feature

Comment: Can't find any Rails documentation that says that a transaction block blocks execution. Anyone know definitively?

Answer (score 0):

What about wrapping a `try` around the `transaction` so that the job is queued up only upon success of the transaction?

Comment: And doesn't `thing.save` return true only after a successful save? ... Did you also try: `ThingProcessor.queue_job(thing_id) if thing.save`. ?

Comment: No, 'thing.save' returns true after Rails AR has passed the request to the DB layer. That's why after_save callbacks can have race condition problems and why there is an after_commit callback that waits until after the DB has written and returns a confirmation. The problem with adding conditionals or try blocks is that the job would not be queued when the race condition is hit. More code would have to be added to circle back and try to queue the job again later. This adds complexity .

Comment: Sorry, I think half my previous comment might be wrong. It is possible that transaction blocks *do* block execution, and since Rails "save" calls are wrapped in transaction blocks, the save call might not actually return "true" until after the database transaction completes successfully. So it would be possible to wrap in a conditional. But doesn't alleviate the problem of having to find a way to re-queue the job.

Comment: based on what you just said, is one EVER guaranteed that a transaction block that completes might not actually be so?  (I could see "change hasn't persisted over to other backups DB servers" but that's a db issue.  But how can the transaction block be of any meaning if it can exit without knowing all the previous statements completed?

Comment: another idea: if you don't need the queued job for a bit, perhaps  give it a future time to fire off, say, 1 minute? To paraphrase Lt Cmdr Data, to a database "that is almost an eternity". :)   Completely depends on what the Thing is and what the queued_job is.   But if it were something that could wait -- and presumably that is one (not all) of the reasons to queue it -- say, looking up a City from a Zipcode or something simplistic -- then forward-queueing the job might work.   You haven't stated enough about the actual problem space for us to offer much advice in that direction, though.

Comment: OK, another suggestion. Set a flag ("up_to_date"? boolean) on the Thing, and have the queued job check the value of the boolean when it fires off. If it's false, then re-queue itself.   (ugh, I hate this. But it might get to you to point B until you have a better solution)

Comment: agree makes sense that transaction block must actually verify db commits before returning control otherwise they'd have no use. My first comment where I say that "save" returns control right after passing control to the db is wrong. "save" is wrapped in a transaction so it won't return control until it confirms db commit. The after_save race condition is orthogonal to this issue. The original code suggested by Brian should run synchronously and not cause race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where by I needed to ensure that a transaction had commited before running a series of action. I ended up using this Gem:

https://github.com/Envek/after_commit_everywhere

It meant that I could do the following:

```
def finalize!
  Order.transaction do
    payment.charge!

    # ...

    # Ensure that we only send out items and perform after actions when the order has defintely be completed
    after_commit { OrderAfterFinalizerJob.perform_later(self) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One gem to allow that is https://github.com/Ragnarson/after_commit_queue

It is a little different than the other answer's `after_commit_everywhere` gem. The `after_commit_everywhere` call seems decoupled from current model being saved or not.

So it might be what you expect or not expect, depending on your use case.