# Why is object not found in DB right after create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, concurrency

We are using ruby on rails, sidekiq for asynch workers and postgresql as DB.

We are creating a new object then we run an asynch worker which tries to get that object from DB. But the asynch worker does not find the object in the first try.

Is this behaviour normal? We have logs which show the object is created_at `08:27:03` then we get an error from the asynch worker at `08:27:03` (because the where query returns NIL)

Later at `08:27:47` the worker retries and finds the object in the DB.

I do not understand how could this happen. Isn't .create() supposed to return after the object was saved in the DB?

Could anyone explain? I suspect some issue related to caching.

```
notif = Notification.create()
Worker.perform_async(notif.id)

def Worker
  def perform(id)
    n = Notification.where(id: id).first # returns NIL
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

From what I have found, `.create()` is not returning after the object is stored in DB, there could be a small delay.

Check this link for more info: https://www.netguru.com/blog/no-object-in-database-ruby

I will try to use `perform_in` for my worker, as someone suggested.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Sidekiq can pick up a job earlier than an object will be physically committed to the DB.

Comment: I thought when .create() returns the object is already stored in the DB. I can hardly find any info regarding this issue. Do you have any reading materials, please? I would like to learn more about .create() behaviour. All I find is that .create is composed of .new and .save

Comment: Also, from my findings I think after_commit_callback should fix the situation, is that right?

Comment: ActiveRecord is almost entirely syncronous* so I don't think that is what is actually happening here. Instead I would guess that `Notification.create` isn't actually saving the record. Change it to `create!` and it might tell you what validation failed.

Comment: There are no validations for my object and the logs show that the object was created. I even accessed the object manually. I found someone who says that .save() is not enough to be sure that the object got into the DB. But I am not sure if that applies for .create as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279792/run-rails-code-after-an-update-to-the-database-has-commited-without-after-commi

Comment: It might happen for example if your Sidekiq workers use DB replica and there is a replication lag.

Comment: Try to delay it a bit with `perform_in` https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs

Comment: Do you have that logic wrapped in a Transaction?

Comment: I do not have that logic wrapped in a Transaction.

Comment: That perform_in looks good to me, it seems like it should solve it. I also found this link which literally explain my problem. Thank you all for your help. https://www.netguru.com/blog/no-object-in-database-ruby